# How many coffee beans fit in volume X?

Tags: geometry

Good day dear Internet.

I am Building a table out of palette wood. I want to fill in gaps between the boards with kitchen stuff, pepper grains, coffee beans and so on and fill that up with epoxy resin.

I wonder if there is a way to mathematically aproximate the amount of resin I will need.

For instance, the volume to fill would be 80cm by 10cm by 2.2cm, an average coffe bean be 1,5cm long and 0.8cm wide and 0.5cm thick, how many fit (whole) in there and what is the leftover volume?

Of course there will be an error margin.

Comment: This ultimately comes down to some kind of [packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems).  Even with very uniform objects (rather than coffee beans), these are difficult problems.  If your goal is to build a table, "trial and error" might be you best bet (perhaps start with a somewhat scaled down version to get a reasonable approximation).

Comment: Coffee beans might even absorb some of the resin. Even if they didn't, their shape varies enough to make packing estimation hard. For example, vibrating the "scree" will usually pack it better, reducing the volume. But, if you have objects with different densities, vibrating it tends to bring the less dense ones to the surface, and more dense ones to the bottom. I would recommend you do a couple of small (matchbox-sized or slightly larger?) test pieces. You might even wish to tint the resin..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As menti0ned in the comments, trial and error might be the best option. But since you've asked, here is some math to give an upper bound: Assume a single coffee bean has the shape of an ellipsoid with axis lengths $a$, $b$ and $c$.  Then its volume is $\pi/6\cdot abc$, whereas the quader it is inscribed in has volume $abc$, i.e. $(1-\pi/6)\approx48$% of the volume of the quader is leftover.

If the whole gap is filled in that way (namely with ellipsoids neatly sitting inside of boxes which are aligned next to each other), then the whole gap will have roughly $48$% leftover volume as well. Since in reality the coffee beans will be packed more densely, I would assume that you do not have more than $48$%$\times 8\times1\times0.22=0.92$ liters leftover volume.